# React Big Calendar - change the agenda range to include all days of the current month only

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to modify the visible range showed in the agenda view so it includes all the days from the current month only, so far this is my attempt:

```jsx
const Scheduler = () => {
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date())
  const onNavigate = newDate => {
    const d = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), 1);
    setCurrentDate(d)  
  }

  return (
    <Calendar
      onNavigate={onNavigate}
      date={currentDate}
    />
  )
}
```

So because per default the `length` prop is set to 30 to accomplish my goal I just need to set the day of `date` prop to always be first one, this is why inside `onNavigate` function I create a new Date object (called `d` in my code) in which I basically copy the Date object being received by the function but set its day to 1.

This works only the first time I click the next button, if I attempt to go to future months nothing happens and when I log the Date object received by the function(`newDate` in the code) it changes only the first time the function is called but after that the Date it receives is always the same one.

This happens only for the agenda view and only when going to future months.

I can go just fine to past months in the agenda view and in the calendar view I can go to future and past months without problems.

PD: I omited unnecessary props like events, localizer... etc because I think they are not relevant as the calendar works fine is just this functionality I'm trying to change that is not working as expected.